# Saving a video/GIF file for the Open AI GymTaxi environment

Tags: python-3.x, animated-gif, openai-gym

I am trying to make a GIF file for the Open AI Gym Taxi environment. I can see quite a few codes for the environments that are image objects. But Taxi environment is String and I am not sure how to save the rendered environments as a jpg or a png file.

Here's what I have:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Taxi-v2')
state=env.reset()
while True:
    t += 1
    env.render()
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
        break
env.close()
```

I have tried:

```
env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, './video/',video_callable=lambda episode_id: True,force = True)
```

but this just creates a json file.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have FFmpeg installed? If not just install it with:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

for Debian, or:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

on OS X.

**Edit (clarification):**

The gym video recorder starts by creating frames per second and dumping their metadata in a json format, but before rendering these frames it requires an encoder for compression therefore a subprocess of finding an ffmpeg encoder is initiated which might lead to a dependency error if it was not found and the metadata of the first frames.For further understanding check the source code listed under `gym/wrappers/monitoring/video_recorder.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a direct way to do this, but I installed asciinema (https://asciinema.org/docs/usage) with

```
apt-get install asciinema
```

to animate the JSON files that OpenAI creates. I then took a screen capture (using something like peek https://github.com/phw/peek) of the output using this command:

```
asciinema play openaigym.video.0.272453.video000000.json
```

which produced:

[image: GIF of output]